# Working with GIT branch

Tags: git, git-branch, git-workflow

I understand the GIT workflow very well.I have a `master` branch and then I checkout a `develop` branch. After that, I checkout a `feature` branch. On the `feature` branch I edited a file. When I checkout back to the `develop` branch. I saw that file has been edited. I start not to understand because I thought when you do something with a file on a branch, it will not affect the same file on another branch until you merge both branches. Can someone explain why it affected the same file on the `develop` branch when I edited that file on the `feature` branch? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to commit the change in the branch `feature`.

Answer (score 0):

When you edit a file on a branch you edit that version from that branch. When you want to change to another branch you have to commit your changes first or you can use `git stash` to save that state and you can restore it with `git stash pop` if you want to work again on that branch.

When you have changed files its possible to change the branch ich the file is not modified on the branch you are changing to. But you have to be patient then you have the state from the develop branch for example. When the file has changes then you get an error.

Answer (score 0):

When you checkout from a master branch to another branch and do changes on that branch you should always stash your changes on that branch using "git stash" or you can commit the changes and push that branch to the remote server.

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding could use some refinement.

Checkout updates the index and worktree, but if you've modified the indexed and/or worktree content for a file and the new checkout hasn't, your modifications are preserved.

If the new checkout *has* also modified that file's content, you can even have git merge those changes with yours during checkout with the `--merge` option (git will refuse the checkout if both you and the new checkout have changed a file and you don't ask it to merge the changes).

So if you're in a file and notice a fix that should be done on another branch, you switch to that branch, add just the one fix, commit that, and switch back.  Your worktree isn't for working on a branch, it's for working on content and recording changes where you like.

To be sure you haven't missed any other fundamentals (and what you've asked about here is very fundamental stuff), I'd say go back over all the documentation with the idea that you don't know *anything* about git.  Look at it with completely fresh eyes.